# View with a subquery error : View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, view

In MySQL why does the following error occur when trying to create a view with a subquery in the FROM clause?

```
View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause
```

Also, what are some good workarounds for this limitation?

Are there any workarounds that work for any subquery in the FROM clause or are there some queries that can not be expressed without using a subquery in the FROM clause? My query is as afollows:

```
SELECT vg.tender_id, 
       sum(amount) as sumofamount, 
       sum(amount) - lc_amt_value as totalamount
FROM com_payments as vg
JOIN (SELECT tender_id, sum(lc_amt_value) as lc_amt_value
      FROM commercial_sales_custpo_process
      GROUP BY tender_id
) as t on vg.tender_id = t.tender_id
GROUP BY tender_id
```

Comment: It seems that MySQL 5.7 already support from with subquery.

Comment: iam using 5.6. Let me see if there is a way i can update the server. Thank you